# Syntax Error "Missing parentheses" Image Forensics tool Imago

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, image-processing

[image: Error Image]

I have installed imago but whenever I am trying to run It.It shows a Syntax Error.
Kindly help.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Kindly help now.

Comment: are you sure you the imago module is compatible with your python version? It looks like you are using Python 3 while imago is written in Python 2 (or viceversa)

Comment: Looks like this [library](https://github.com/redaelli/imago-forensics) is Python 2.7 only.

Comment: @PietroMarsella I do have python 2 installed and the module is for python 2 but how do I install and run It with Python 2. From the last time It's automatically running with python 3.7 .

Comment: @Georgy I looked there but there was no solution posted there.

Comment: try running it with the -2 flag. It works on Windows for me

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/redaelli/imago-forensics this module requires python 2.7.

Your screenshot shows you are using python 3.7.  This is not the correct python version for this module.

You will need to install python 2.7